# Nvprof internal error 15:120

Tags: cuda, profiler, nvidia

I'm trying to run `nvprof` profiler to see where my program is spending more time.

But i always get this error:

`======== NVPROF is profiling gpu_stuff...
======== Command: gpu_stuff
======== Error: Internal profiler error 15:120======== Warning: Application returned non-zero code 255
======== Error: failed to read result file.
======== Warning: make sure cudaDeviceReset() is called before application exit to flush profile data.`

I'm calling `cudaDeviceReset()` at the end of code and it is not working yet.

Obs: I have no `X-server` disponible, i need to use the profiler in command-line.

Comment: Does your application run normally if you don't use nvprof ?  What happens if you try profiling a simple example like the vecadd sample in the cuda samples?

Comment: What is your driver version? Is it compatible with your CUDA toolkit version?

Comment: @RobertCrovella - I tried to profile the example you said and it didn't works.
@YuZhou - Due to your comment i'm able to use `nvprof` now. The version of my driver was not compatible with my CUDA toolkit version. Can you answer the question? Thus i can accept your answer and mark the question solved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Yu Zhou
It's because of your CUDA toolkit version not compatible with your driver version.